# Quero verificar se um link foi clicado e redirecioná-lo com o Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, login, redirect

No rodapé (*footer*) tem uma imagem que é *link* para uma página - externa ao meu site - do Google Docs. Quero restringir o acesso a essa página do Google Docs da seguinte maneira: - Se quem clicou na imagem/*link* não estiver *logado*, chamo a página *login.php* do Wordpress (WP); - Se ele estiver logado abro a página do Google Docs.

Pensei em utilizar o arquivo `functions.php` do WP, a idéia é mais ou menos essa, só não sei como verificar o clique com PHP ou com o próprio WP:

```
function logadoRedireciona() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { // se estiver logado 
        // vá para o link
        wp_redirect( 'https://docs.google.com/' );
        exit;
    } else { // se não 
        // faça o login
        wp_login_form();
    }
} 
add_action ( 'wp_footer' , 'logadoRedireciona' );
```

O WP tem alguma *template tag* que verifica *links* ou *URLs*? Ou utilizando o PHP, como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

### A imagem será a mesma tanto para logado ou não:

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo '<a href="https://docs.google.com/"><img src="imagem.png"></a>';
} else {
    echo '<a href="'.site_url().'/logar?jaCliquei=1"><img src="imagem.png"></a>';
}
?>
```

Quando ele clicar no link uma condição criada no `functions.php` vai redirecionar o usuário após o `login` detectando o `jaCliquei=1`:

```
    function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {

    global $user;
    if ( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
        //if admin
        if ( in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles ) ) {
            // redirecionamento padrão
            return $redirect_to;
        } else {
            if($_GET['jaCliquei'] == 1) {

             //AQUI O REDIRECIONAMENTO PARA O DOCS
              wp_redirect( 'https://docs.google.com/' );
            }else{

             //Login padrão de usuário comum
             return home_url();

            } 


        }
    } else {
        return $redirect_to;
    }
}

add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

-

Comment: Não testei, mas ver se dar certo.

Comment: Obrigado. Sou bem novato no WP, por isso me perdoe pelas perguntas: o primeiro trecho do código vai no footer.php? e o segundo no functions, certo?

Comment: Exatamente!.....

Comment: Mais uma coisinha a imagem, a imagem/link em questão foi inserida no rodapé por intermédio de um widget. O tema que estou usando é o crumina (widget, Imagem JetPack). Complicou, né?

Comment: A questão é saber se tem como detectar se está logado ou não para por um link na imagem dependendo disso.

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi o seu problema, você chegou quase lá. 
No rodapé do seu site você vai exbir o link normalmente e na pagina dos Docs que você vai fazer o `if`

```
<?php  if (is_user_logged_in()): ?>
     //Conteudo do doc    
<?php else: ?>
// Fomulario de Login
<?php endif; ?>
```

Acho que isso vai te ajudar.